# Proving $\cot(\beta)\cot({\gamma})+\cot(\alpha)\cot(\gamma)+\cot(\alpha)\cot(\beta)=1$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Proof that for every triangle $\triangle_\text{ABC}$ in the euclidian space $\mathbb{E}^2$ with the angles $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$ the following is true:  $$\cot(\beta)\cot(\gamma)+\cot(\alpha)\cot(\gamma)+\cot(\alpha)\cot(\beta)=1$$

What I tried so far:

Replace $\cot(\alpha),\cot(\beta)$ and $\cot(\gamma)$ with $\cot(\alpha)=\frac{\cos(\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha)},
\cot(\beta)=\frac{\cos(\beta)}{\sin(\beta)}$ and $\cot(\gamma)=\frac{\cos(\gamma)}{\sin(\gamma)}$ to get:

$$\frac{\cos(\beta)}{\sin(\beta)}\frac{\cos(\gamma)}{\sin(\gamma)}+\frac{\cos(\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha)}\frac{\cos(\gamma)}{\sin(\gamma)}+\frac{\cos(\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha)}\frac{\cos(\beta)}{\sin(\beta)}=1$$

Then maybe because $\sin^2(\alpha)+\cos^2(\alpha)=1$ you could replace $1$ with $1=\sin^2(\alpha)+\cos^2(\alpha)+\sin^2(\beta)+\cos^2(\beta)-\sin^2(\gamma)-\cos^2(\gamma)$

So in conclusion you would get:

$\frac{\cos(\beta)}{\sin(\beta)}\frac{\cos(\gamma)}{\sin(\gamma)}+\frac{\cos(\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha)}\frac{\cos(\gamma)}{\sin(\gamma)}+\frac{\cos(\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha)}\frac{\cos(\beta)}{\sin(\beta)}=\sin^2(\alpha)+\cos^2(\alpha)+\sin^2(\beta)+\cos^2(\beta)-\sin^2(\gamma)-\cos^2(\gamma)$

It's an old geometry exam question that I don't really know how to solve as I don't know how to proceed from here or if this is even the right way. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: I would start from the statement $\tan(\alpha + \beta) = \tan(\pi - \gamma) = \cot(\gamma)$, and expand the left hand side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\cot(\beta)\cot(\gamma)+\cot(\alpha)\cot(\gamma)+\cot(\alpha)\cot(\beta)=1 \tag{1}$$
$$
\begin{align}
&\iff \cot(\alpha) \left(\cot(\beta)+\cot(\gamma)  \right) = 1- \cot(\beta)\cot(\gamma)\\
&\iff \cot(\alpha)\frac{\cos(\beta)\sin(\gamma)+\cos(\gamma)\sin(\beta)}{\sin(\beta)\sin(\gamma)} = \frac{\sin(\beta)\sin(\gamma)-\cos(\gamma)\cos(\beta)}{\sin(\beta)\sin(\gamma)}\\
&\iff \cot(\alpha)= \frac{-\cos(\beta+\gamma)}{\sin(\beta+\gamma)}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

As $\beta +\gamma = \pi -\alpha$, we have $\cos(\beta+\gamma)=-\cos(\alpha)$ and $\sin(\beta+\gamma) =\sin(\alpha)$, hence $(2)$ holds true.

We deduce that $(1)$ holds true.

Q.E.D

Comment: Thank you for answering! Out of curiosity, how long did it take you to think of this solution?

Comment: To be honest, I think it took me 1 minute. But I had a very solid backgrounds in math when I was pupil.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi,$ and therefore $\tan(\pi-\alpha)=\tan(\beta+\gamma),$ which is equivalent to $$-\tan\alpha=\dfrac{\tan\beta+\tan\gamma}{1-\tan\beta\tan\gamma}.$$ This simplifies to $$\tan\alpha+\tan\beta+\tan\gamma=\tan\alpha\tan\beta\tan\gamma.$$
Now divide both sides by the expression in RHS.

Comment: You would need to handle the case separately where either of the angles is $\pi /2\,$.